# Пользовательские маркеры API Яндекс Карт перекрывают друг друга

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В примерах Яндекса есть "Добавление маркера с пользовательским изображением на карту" (https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/examples/cases/marker-custom-icon), но с этим примером есть проблема и непонятно как ее решать.

Если жёлтую капибару поставить поверх фиолетовой (просто в common.ts прописать её первой) и немного уменьшить масштаб, то она заблокирует события на части фиолетовой. Это как-то связано с тем, что она смещена относительно своего настоящего положения и то место, где она была бы без смещения блокирует элементы, расположенные под ним - ни наведение не работает, ни клики.

Пример на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полупрозрачный синий квадрат - фактическое расположение жёлтой капибары (смотрю через консоль Google Chrome) и в этой области наведение и клики по фиолетовой не срабатывают.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы маркеры друг другу не мешались?

Comment: Без конкретного примера кода сложно сказать однозначно. Но похоже, что вам нужно корректно задавать смещение меток при выставленном размере. Поработайте с .icon-marker в common.css